# How do I move 1 row up based on a date value for Fiscal Calendar in excel?

Tags: excel

My question is, if I have a date entered in in Column A, I would like the formula to look at that date and compare it to a lookup, if it's within that set of date ranges go to the previous row. What I mean by this is for example:

[image: Fiscal Weeks]

This is the lookup (Would be on a different sheet in the Workbook) that I would be using as a reference. In Column A, a Date would be entered in, for example, `10/30/2019`, If `10/30/2019` is entered in Column A I would like the formula to look at the lookup and determine that it's within `10/06/2019 - 11/02/2019` range, then go to the previous row, `09/01/2019 - 10/05/2019`

```
    A           |             B
10/30/2019      |  09/01/2019 - 10/05/2019
```

That is what I would want it too result in after everything is calculated correctly. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably split your lookup values into two columns, beginning and end of period, then you can compare if the date is between them. How have you tried to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution involves setting up a second lookup array listing individual dates with a second column for a key to your first lookup array. So it would look like this:

### [image]

Then add the key to your original lookup like this:

[image]

---

Now you will just need a formula with two nested vlookups. The first is looking up the date entered and returning the key value minus 1. The second is looking up that result to return your desired date range. It would look like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$158,2,FALSE)-1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

A1 is the date entered in column A. Adjust the cell references and lookup ranges according to how you set up your sheet.